# Laravel query builder - Where in list of numbers

Tags: php, laravel

I have 
$vlsalesitemid="11,12,13,"

```
$query=DB::table('st_temp_sales')->where('brand_id', $brandid)
                                 ->wherein $vlsalesitemid
                                 ->get();
return $query;
```

How can I type the where in using laravel ? and can I use it with this format of list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) string to get an array of IDs. Then use the correct syntax for [`whereIn()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses):

```
->whereIn('id', explode(',', $vlsalesitemid))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$vlsalesitemid="11,12,13,";
$val_array = explode(',', $vlsalesitemid);
$query=DB::table('st_temp_sales')->where('brand_id', $brandid)
                                 ->whereIn('your_id', $val_array)->get();
return $query;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses):

```
$query=DB::table('st_temp_sales')->where('brand_id', $brandid)
                                 ->whereIn('id', explode(',', $vlsalesitemid))
                                 ->get();
return $query
```